# Image retrieval with Picasso from Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this very strange bug where I upload an image from the gallery and it clearly works because I can see it in firebase storage and the image's URL is in Firestore too. For some reason the images are not loading in the list view only after I refresh the app. I tried using startActivityForResult in order to refresh the Homepage activity so the images get loaded. For some reason the onActivityResult is never called so I can't use that method.

HomePage.activity

```
public class HomePage extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private static final String KEY_FIRSTNAME = "firstName";

    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    String userID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

    private DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("users").document(userID);


    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<Data> dataArrayList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);


        Button signOut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signOut);
        Button add_journey = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_journey);
        signOut.setOnClickListener(this);
        add_journey.setOnClickListener(this);

        listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        dataArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        loadDataInListView();
       // loadName();
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.signOut:
                Intent intent_signOut = new Intent(HomePage.this, MainActivity.class);
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                startActivity(intent_signOut);
                break;
            case R.id.add_journey:
                Intent intent_add = new Intent(HomePage.this, AddJourney.class);
                startActivity(intent_add);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void loadDataInListView() {
        db.collection("users").document(userID).collection("journeys").get()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        if(!queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()){
                            List<DocumentSnapshot> list = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments();

                            for(DocumentSnapshot d : list){
                                Data data = d.toObject(Data.class);

                                dataArrayList.add(data);
                            }

                            Adapter adapter = new Adapter(HomePage.this, dataArrayList);

                            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(HomePage.this, "No data found in database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(HomePage.this, "Fail to load data..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

CustomAdapter.java

```
public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Data> {

    public Adapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<Data> dataArrayList) {
        super(context, 0, dataArrayList);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View listitemView = convertView;
        if(listitemView == null){
            listitemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        }

        Data data = getItem(position);

        TextView title = listitemView.findViewById(R.id.journey_title);

        ImageView imageView = listitemView.findViewById(R.id.image);

        title.setText(data.getTitle());

        Picasso.get().load(data.getImgUrl()).into(imageView);

        listitemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               String title = data.getTitle();
               String description = data.getDescription();
               String journeyID = data.getJourneyID();
               String imgUrl = data.getImgUrl();

               Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), EditJourney.class);
               intent.putExtra("title", title);
               intent.putExtra("description", description);
               intent.putExtra("journeyID", journeyID);
               intent.putExtra("imgUrl", imgUrl);

               getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return listitemView;
    }



}
```

AddJourney.java - this is where I press add it redirects me back to Homepage without seeing the images. I can only see the images after refreshing/restarting the app

```
public class AddJourney extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private EditText title;
    private EditText description;
    private ImageView journeyIMG;
    private Button uploadCamera;
    private Button uploadGallery;

    private Button add;

    String jTitle;
    String jDescription;
    String userID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    public static int CODE = 2;

    FirebaseFirestore fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    private StorageReference storageReference;
    StorageReference filepath;
    Uri uri;

    DocumentReference docRef = fStore.collection("users").document(userID).collection("journeys").document();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_journey);

        title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title);
        description = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.description);
        journeyIMG = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
        add.setOnClickListener(this);

        uploadCamera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.upload_camera);
        uploadCamera.setOnClickListener(this);

        uploadGallery = (Button) findViewById(R.id.upload_gallery);
        uploadGallery.setOnClickListener(this);

        storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.add:
                addJourney();
                Intent intent = new Intent(AddJourney.this, HomePage.class);
                intent.setFlags(0);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 78);
                break;
            case R.id.upload_camera:
                imgCamera();

                break;
            case R.id.upload_gallery:
                imgGallery();
        }
    }

    private void imgGallery() {
        Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(pickPhoto, 0);
    }

    private void imgCamera() {
        Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(takePicture, 1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case 0:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    uri = data.getData();
                    journeyIMG.setImageURI(uri);

                    filepath = storageReference.child(userID).child(uri.getLastPathSegment());

                }
                break;
            case 1:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                    uri = data.getData();

                    filepath = storageReference.child(userID).child(uri.getLastPathSegment());

                    break;
                }
        }
    }

    private void addJourney() {
        jTitle = title.getText().toString();
        jDescription = description.getText().toString();

        Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();

        data.put("title", jTitle);
        data.put("description", jDescription);
        data.put("journeyID", null);
        data.put("imgUrl", null);

        fStore.collection("users").document(userID).collection("journeys").add(data)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                        Toast.makeText(AddJourney.this, "Successfully added journey!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

                        filepath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                filepath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                        fStore.collection("users").document(userID).collection("journeys").document(documentReference.getId()).update("imgUrl", uri.toString());
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });

                        fStore.collection("users").document(userID).collection("journeys").document(documentReference.getId()).update(
                                "journeyID", documentReference.getId());

                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(AddJourney.this, "Failed to add data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Data.java

```
public class Data {
    private String title;
    private String imgUrl;
    private String description;
    private String journeyID;

    public Data(){}

    public Data(String title, String imgUrl, String journeyID) {
        this.title = title;
        this.imgUrl = imgUrl;
        this.journeyID = journeyID;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getImgUrl() {
        return imgUrl;
    }

    public void setImgUrl(String imgUrl) {
        this.imgUrl = imgUrl;
    }

    public String getJourneyID() {
        return journeyID;
    }

    public void setJourneyID(String journeyID) {
        this.journeyID = journeyID;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

Comment: why use `ListView` ?

Comment: Because I'm new to android development. What should I use?

Comment: recyclerview is the better alternative, might also help you resolve your issues by notifying it about data changes

Comment: How do I do that? is it adapter.notifyDataSetChanged?

Comment: There is **way** too much code in here for us to efficiently help. While there's always a chance that someone spots the problem, chance of that drastically go up if you can deliver a more focused repro. I recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and trying to reproduce the problem in a more limited, isolated setup.